# Speed up "find or create" postgres query that searches from id and timestamp

Tags: sql, c, postgresql

I've got a postgres query that I'm using to "find or create" a record, however, it is taking ~60-80ms to complete with ~20k rows, and it is part of a loop. Running the whole loop is starting to drag out, currently at ~20s, and only getting longer (the whole loop is inside a transaction). I'm using the market_id and a timestamp to select the rows.

I suspect it is the timestamp field that is giving me trouble, but I'm not sure. I'm using  in C.

Here is how I create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE market_summary(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  market_id INT,
  market_name VARCHAR(20),
  high FLOAT,
  low FLOAT,
  volume FLOAT,
  last FLOAT,
  base_volume FLOAT,
  timestamp TIMESTAMP,
  bid FLOAT,
  ask FLOAT,
  open_buy_orders INT,
  open_sell_orders INT,
  previous_day FLOAT,
  market_creation_date TIMESTAMP,
  created_at TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

And here is a sample of the query I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO market_summary(market_id,market_name,high,low,volume,last,base_volume,timestamp,bid,ask,open_buy_orders,open_sell_orders,previous_day,market_creation_date) 
SELECT 19, 'BTC-BITB', 0.000001, 0.000001, 37359913.914823, 0.000001, 21.940584, '2017-08-18T00:13:43.643', 0.000001, 0.000001, 310, 4255, 0.000001, '2015-02-15T23:07:32.777' 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT (market_id,timestamp) FROM market_summary 
      WHERE market_id = 19 AND timestamp::timestamp = to_timestamp('2017-08-18T00:13:43.643', 'YYYY-MM-DDThh24:mi:ss.ms')
  );
SELECT * FROM market_summary 
    WHERE market_id = 19 AND timestamp::timestamp = to_timestamp('2017-08-18T00:13:43.643', 'YYYY-MM-DDThh24:mi:ss.ms');
```

And finally the EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
    Insert on market_summary  (cost=19778.63..19778.69 rows=1 width=170)
->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=19778.63..19778.69 rows=1 width=170)
      ->  Result  (cost=19778.63..19778.64 rows=1 width=364)
            One-Time Filter: (NOT $0)
            InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
              ->  Seq Scan on market_summary market_summary_1  (cost=0.00..19778.63 rows=1 width=0)
                    Filter: ((market_id = 19) AND ("timestamp" = to_timestamp('2017-08-18T00:13:43.643'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DDThh24:mi:ss.ms'::text)))
```

Is there a way to speed this up significantly?

Edit:
I forgot to put in the relationship to market, Market has many MarketSummary.

Edit 2:
The Market Table:

```
CREATE TABLE markets(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  created_at TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: The issue is probably the running of a loop.  Set-based operations are preferred in SQL.

Comment: if i understand it correctly you need a uniq index on (market_id,timestamp) and insert with on confilct do nothig

Comment: Wouldn't a unique index on market id stop me from adding more of the same market? And if I put one on timestamp, what if (however small the chance) there is another timestamp in another with a different market id, wouldn't that cause an error too? Or can you put a unique index on (market_id AND timestamp)? I probably should have been more clear in the question. Market has many market summary, market<--->>market_summary

Comment: It *looks like* market_id should be a foreign key, and market_name depends on it. What is the cardinality of market_id?

Comment: market_name is a redundant column, just there for ease. I'll add the market table to the question in an edit

Comment: Denormalisation is the root of all evil. (plus: loops)

Comment: Sorry could you expand on that? In terms of the "its the loop" that's the problem, I've got the loop encased in a transaction, which mitigates some of the loop problem? (or am I missing something?)

Comment: `the loop`will fire the query repeatedly, with different values for the insert. That will involve at least  2 round trips to the database plus parsing+executing the query. For every iteration of the loop. creating+filling a(temp) table from your data, and inserting(+selecting) the actual table(s) would cost only a few round-trips for the entire batch.

Comment: @PeterDevlin i suggested a multi column index https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-multicolumn.html.